# Questions with *many* answers, *most* of which clearly don’t answer the question asked

Tags: discussion, answers, clean-up, convert-to-comment

Sometimes someone will ask a question and then a bunch of people will post answers which clearly show that they did not read the entire question and/or ignored some important parts of it. For example, someone may ask how to do something with certain constraints, but then most of the answers will completely ignore the constraints and post “answers” that clearly do not apply.

For example, [this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/396501/how-can-i-produce-highcpu-load-on-windows/) asks how to induce a CPU load in Windows with only built-in tools, *most* of the answers specifically discuss using third-party programs. At *best*, those should only be comments (related asides), not “answers” because they *don’t* actually answer the question that was asked. Some people even attempted to rationalize their answer by nitpicking the specific wording of the question, but clearly failed to understand the underlying requirement.

What should be done with such questions? I suppose a moderator could go through and convert the disqualified answers to comments (which they should have been in the first place), assuming of course that they are short enough. But what is the best course of action?

**Clarification:** to be clear, I am specifically asking about question which have a *large number* of responses (20+), *most of which* are poor and invalid.

The issue is that simply down-voting or flagging is meaningless and a waste of time because the down-votes waste a bunch of your own rep to do so (again, we are talking about a couple of dozen bad answers, not just one or two), and the flags become repetitive which puts them at risk of being ignored. Plus, a single down-vote does nothing to show that they are bad when the worst offenders have a large number of misguided up-votes.

What I’m wondering is if there is or should be some way to flag the whole thread for review.

Comment: Use your votes. If you feel an answer is not helpful, downvote it. Flag posts that should have been comments.

Comment: So I have to waste a bunch of my own rep to down-vote a couple of dozen answers? What about the answers which got tons of (misguided) up-votes? A single down-vote does nothing for it. I could flag them, but it feels like flagging 75% of the answers in a thread may seem unusual and a mod may simply ignore them and even if I left an explanation, they may just decide that ignoring the constraint is “okay”.

Comment: That's how it works. If **other visitors to the page** found those answers helpful, they are also free to upvote. The OP is not the only person looking for answers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you’re missing the point, the answers are irrelevant to the question that was asked. If other people have *related* questions, then then can ask an appropriate question (assuming they don’t already exist, which they often do). It is absurd to allow people to completely ignore a critical part of the question. If someone asked how to do a quick-sort in C++, would you accept people posting answers in Cobol just because some other, random person may or may not be interested in a Cobol quick-sort algorithm? If that’s what the want, then they should post their own question.

Comment: And again, that’s what comments are for; when you have useful information that is not actually an answer to the question.

Comment: Those are **still answers**. They may be terrible answers, completely missing the point of the question, but they are still answers. You downvote them, you move on. But don't tell others how they should vote, that's my point.

Comment: I’m telling people how to vote (though I do have a problem with people voting foolishly), I’m *asking how these should be cleaned up* when the thread is *full* of these terrible answers. If there were one or two, then voting or flagging may help, but when they make up 80% of the responses, then a more drastic action is needed. That’s my point, and I thought it was pretty clear.

Comment: But I disagree with you as to what makes an answer not an answer. Your examples **are answers** and do **not** need cleaning up! I'm am going to refer to the [many posts on the Not An Answer flag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/not-an-answer) and leave it at that instead.

Comment: They are all perfectly good answers.  The OP has a very unusual requirement with his "can't install software" demand.  That's covered in answers as well, it just isn't a common limitation for others that may Google the question some day.

Comment: That is a pretty horrific example of "let's only answer the title". Pity the first real answer has 1/3 of the votes of the top one.... unfortunately I think that the answer is that there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Downvote. Move on.

Comment: Oops, I [meant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227110/#comment743926_227110) I’m *not* telling people how to vote.

Comment: `The OP has a very unusual requirement with his "can't install software" demand.` @UphillLuge, there’s **nothing** unusual about it. I already explained the constraint may be from a company policy that prevents non-whitelisted programs from running; that’s common in the workplace. As for Google, (1) the OP doesn’t give a damn what interest *other* people may or may not *potentially* have in the question *in the future*, they have a specific question *now* that they want solved. (2) Like I already said, others can simply ask *another* question about third-party programs (or read existing ones).

Comment: @UphillLuge, also, that was just one example. I gave another programming example. How the hell is asking how to do a quick-sort in C++ an "unusual demand"? Do you really think you can justify it if 80% of the answers of the 20 or 30 answers, including the *top-voted answers* give QS algorithms in *other* languages‽

Comment: @Pëkka, assuming your comment was directed at me as an answer to my question (and not to others in response to my question), then I already said, why should I spend a bunch of my rep and even more of my time down-voting and/or flagging 20 or 30 bad answers? Like I said, it’s one thing if there’s one or two bad answers, but I am specifically asking about threads where *almost all* of them are bad. And again, a single down-vote does nothing to some of the bad answers which have 50+ votes; they still *look* like they are popular and good.

Comment: The fact that these answer *did* get upvoted heavily should give you some pause.  Imagining some kind of conspiracy where both the answerers and the voters ignore the unusual demands is stretching it heavily.  The specific needs of the OP are just secondary at SE.

Comment: @UphillLuge, the only pause it gives me is to make me sad that there are so many stupid, illiterate people with itchy clicking-fingers. Once *again*, if people want third-party programs to consume CPU cycles or a Cobol QS algorithm, then they should **ask a separate question**, not bastardize an existing one!

Comment: @down-voters; I take it that you are the kind of people who are of the opinion that if enough people do something bad or wrong, then it magically becomes good and right. Well then let’s just hope that not enough people start raping and murdering children, or we’ll end up in an ancient-Rome meets *The Purge* world.

Comment: @Synetech Sure, the answers probably should've taken the constraints into account, and so should the voters, but what does more damage now - changing the question a little, deleting most of the highly-upvoted answers, or converting them to comments, where they'll get little-to-no visibility?

Comment: @Synetech Because rep isn't that important? Not casting a downvote because you lose a reputation point is silly. Re answers with 50+ upvotes, that is true, +1 - but that happening is going to be a *huge* exception. Not sure what happened in the example you show, having that many answers ignore a constraint seems weird. I don't think it's the norm though.

Comment: If the answer is poor or wrong, downvote it; that's exactly what the purpose of downvoting is designed to indicate. If your concern is more about your own reputation than the quality of the answers, you probably shouldn't be here. If the answers really are poor, enough users will downvote it so that it will either end up edited to improve it (in which case you can retract your downvote) or deleted by the author or the negative vote count, in which case you regain any reputation you lost. You're trying to use flags to protect yourself, instead of using them to protect the quality of  this site.

Comment: @KenWhite, maybe you should bother to read before opening your mouth. If you had bothered, you would have understood the problem instead of cherry-picking one or two sentences to insult me about.

Comment: @Pëkka, yes, down-voting makes sense when there is a point. Like I said, when there are 30+ bad answers and a bunch of them already have 40+ up-votes, then down-voting is like spitting in the ocean: completely meaningless. Yes, it is unusual, and that is exactly what I am asking about cleaning up. The description for the [`clean-up`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clean-up) tag, perfectly describes what I was trying to do here, but apparently nobody cares.

Comment: @Synetech consider the possibility that we *do* care, but that there simply is no better way to deal with this currently.  What are we supposed to do? But either way, I'm sure that your asking this here has added plenty of downvotes to the bad answers

Comment: @Synetech: I can read perfectly well, and I didn't say anything insulting. I commented on a post that I understand perfectly well - you're wanting to use flags to avoid casting votes on bad answers. What part of that did I get wrong? Apparently, I'm not the only one you've failed to communicate your meaning to here, as your post has a negative 7 vote count. Perhaps you should learn to write better to more clearly communicate your intent before opening **your** mouth and accusing others of lacking the ability to read.

Answer (score 3):

> I am specifically asking about question which have a large number of responses (20+), most of which are poor and invalid.

The general recommended course of action for this kind of thing is downvoting.

You shouldn't flag for removal because a constraint on the question is being ignored - that action is reserved for actual non-answers.

> why should I spend a bunch of my rep and even more of my time down-voting and/or flagging 20 or 30 bad answers

Because you're a community-minded individual, losing a reputation point isn't all that important, and you're making Stack Overflow a slightly better place through it.

I agree, the example you show is really crazy and the top voted answer shouldn't be there.

But then, I don't think it is the norm. (And the question arguably made the mistake of not putting the constraint into the title.)

There are some isolated instances of bad answers having many upvotes. We live with them because individual downvotes will eventually press them down, and comments can be used to make clear it isn't a good answer.

As long as it's not a widespread problem, the occasional fluke in the system is okay.  Having mods remove answers on the grounds that they don't take a specific aspect of an answer into account is not a good idea - it's rarely going to be as clear and easy to judge as it may be here.

Comment: Note that down voting a poor answer *can* case it to kick into the low quality review queue where it may garner either delete votes or recommend to delete reviews which *can* result in a return of the rep spent down voting poor answers (with the deletion of the answer through a community moderation process).

Comment: @MichaelT, and what about the other 30 bad answers? Doing each and every one individually is absurd. There should be a way to flag the whole page for review when the whole thing is that rotten.

Comment: @Synetech who would respond to the flag? Moderators are not supposed to judge the correctness of answers. This isn't an ideal situation but it's rare enough not to be a catastrophe. Stuff like this is bound to happen occasionally in a pool of seven million questions.

Comment: Then I guess there’s no point to the `clean-up` tag if nobody cares about cleaning things up and when someone does, everybody rips on it and down-votes it and says to “move on”. That kind of blasé attitude tells me not to bother, so I won’t. I was just wondering if there was a good way to clean these messes up, but forget it. If nobody else cares, then why should I waste my time? Lesson learned.

Comment: @Synetech you didn't ask for a cleanup. You asked what should be done in general. I told you what, to the best of my knowledge, is the best way to do it. I'm afraid I don't have 30 million dollars lying around right now so I can't buy Stack Exchange and order the team to create a better way. I don't see where I "ripped" on your question; in fact, I upvoted it